# error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _OpenSSL_add_all_algorithms referenced in function __VerifyLicence@4

Tags: c++, visual-c++, openssl

I have project working with release mode. However, when I convert and build it in DEBUG mode its showing below error:

```
error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _OpenSSL_add_all_algorithms referenced in function __VerifyLicence@4
```

I'm not able to clearly get why this linker error. Is it due to that, I'm still using RELEASE version of OpenSSL? If yes, from where can I get DEBUG version of OpenSSL and integrate that in my code?

If No, how can I resolve this error?

My settings: Configuration Properties -> C/C++ -> Code Generation -> Runtime Libarary -> Multi-threaded Debug DLL (/MDd)

Note: Just before this error, I'm getting one warning as well:

```
LINK : warning LNK4098: defaultlib 'MSVCRT' conflicts with use of other libs; use /NODEFAULTLIB:library
```

I have ignored this warning.

Please help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is an undefined reference/unresolved external symbol error and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix)

Comment: Are you using OpenSSL directly? Or is some DRM/licensing package providing it? It almost sounds like a third party providing DRM/licensing packages removed the symbol so you could not get into a debug configuration.